# WebStorm search for action custom hotkey

Tags: webstorm

I cannot find `search for action` in the keymap.

Is it possible to change the key combination (`Ctrl+Shift+A`) to something else?

Comment: Screenshots please (the screen or action that you want to change shortcut for). Right now I'm not sure what exactly you are talking about. But in general : `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- find the action you want and assign another (or additional) shortcut. You can also search for actions by assigned shortcut -- use the button next to the search field.

Comment: @LazyOne Just press ctrl+shift+a and the search for action dialog will open. I want to remap it to another combination. But I cannot find it in the keymap settings

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for `search action`. But the setting is called `find action`